# complex jquery/css selector

Tags: jquery-selectors, css-selectors

I need a selector for this code:

```
    <div class="panel-heading BWHeadingForSection">
<a style="text-decoration:none" href="#faq-cat-1-sub-2" data-parent="#accordion-cat-2" data-toggle="collapse" tabindex="90">
<i class="fa fa-truck fa-lg"></i>
  UPS Deutschland
<span class="pull-right">
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
</span>
</a>
</div>
```

And I tried that:

```
 $('div.BWHeadingForSection a[href~="#faq-cat-1-sub-'+globalcarriernumber+'"]').on("click", function(){
                count++;
                if(count%2==0){
                    $("#faq-cat-1-sub-"+globalcarriernumber).slideToggle();

                    //why doesn't this selector work?
                    //if ( $(this+">span i").hasClass('plus') ) {
                    //    $(this+">span i").removeClass('plus').addClass('minus');
                   // }

                   //this selector work's, at least it enters the if -block
                   if ( $('div.BWHeadingForSection a[href~="#faq-cat-1-sub-'+globalcarriernumber+'"]>span i').hasClass('plus') ) {
                    $('div.BWHeadingForSection a[href~="#faq-cat-1-sub-'+globalcarriernumber+'"]>span i').removeClass('glyphicon glyphicon-plus').addClass('glyphicon glyphicon-minus');
                    }
                }else{
                    $("#faq-cat-1-sub-"+globalcarriernumber).hide();
                }
            });
```

The relevant line is "$(this+">span i")" and/or "$('div.BWHeadingForSection a[href~="#faq-cat-1-sub-'+globalcarriernumber+'"]>span i')" , which needs some adjustment. I have to replace that "plus"("") with "minus".

If I use the FireBug debugger I get for "$('div.BWHeadingForSection a[href~="#faq-cat-1-sub-'+globalcarriernumber+'"]>span i')" ,it goes into that if-block, but the symbol is still the same. And if I use "$(this+">span i")" I get(when I hove over it) : "a#faq-cat-1-sub-2",but it's not entering the if-block.

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you are mixing types here. The function $(...) accepts either an object (a DOM node or a jQuery object) *or* a selector string but not a concatenation of both.

So better try `$(this).find('span i')`.

As far as I can see in your code snippet, the element you will find then, has the css classes 'glyphicon' and 'glyphicon-plus', but no class 'plus'. So you probably won't be able to remove that. Maybe you want to remove 'glyphicon-plus' and add 'glyphicon-minus'?

Comment: yes, I want to remove 'glyphicon-plus' and add 'glyphicon-minus'

Comment: Ok, now  my code looks like  that: "                        if ($(this).find('span i').hasClass('plus') ) {
                            $(this).find('span i').removeClass('glyphicon glyphicon-plus').addClass('glyphicon glyphicon-minus');
                        }" it enters the if-block, but it does not replace the css-class...what's wrong here ?

Comment: I'm surprised that you enter the if-block since the element still does not have a class 'plus'. It should say hasClass('glyphicon-plus'). Other than that, I can't see any problem (besides that you could express your code a bit more elegant, but that is surely not your main problem now).

Comment: That's strange now i changed it to "                        if ($(this).find('span i').hasClass('glyphicon-plus') ) {
                            $(this).find('span i').removeClass('glyphicon glyphicon-plus').addClass('glyphicon glyphicon-minus');
                        }" and it works(it enters that if-block and replaces thae class name). mmh... but thank you for helping :)